# How to avoid ValueError when calling StyleFrame.apply_style_by_indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, styleframe

Currently I'm having a big list of StyleFrame objects. Some of the cells from some dataframes i want to color the background based on their value: > 1 in red and <=1 in green. I think that multiple calls of "apply_style_by_indexes" method creates multiple named styles and I don;t know how to avoid it.

```
red_shade = "F85C4D"
    green_shade = "90EE90"
    for key in dataframe_dict_keys:
        sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf[key] <= threshold],
                                  styler_obj=Styler(bg_color=green_shade),
                                  cols_to_style=key)
        sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf[key] > threshold],
                                  styler_obj=Styler(bg_color=red_shade),
                                  cols_to_style=key)
```

The error is raised while calling ".to_excel" method, which is called for multiple StyleFrame objects

```
 dic["dataframe"].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=country_code, startrow=idx, index=True, best_fit=list(dic["keys"]))
```

EDIT:

```
    def __apply_colors_based_on_value(self, sf, dataframe_dict_keys, threshold):
        for key in dataframe_dict_keys:
            sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf[key] <= threshold],
                                      styler_obj=Styler(bg_color="F85C4D",
                                      cols_to_style=key)
            sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf[key] > threshold],
                                      styler_obj=Styler(bg_color="F85C4D",
                                      cols_to_style=key)
```

WHERE:
**sf** - StyleFrame instance,
**dataframe_dict_keys** - list of columns (header) of the StyleFrame,
**dic** - dict{"dataframe": StyleFrame objects, "keys": List[str] # header columns

Comment: For completeness, what are `dataframe_dict_keys` and `dic`? Alternatively, can you provide a full [mcve]? Also, what error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the latest version (3.0.5)

Comment: @DeepSpace Is it more understandable? Also using styleframe 3.4.0

Comment: Did you mean 3.0.4? If so, try to update to 3.0.5. I tried to reproduce the issue but did not manage to. If it still happens then provide a full [mcve]